# Surrounding one group with special characters in using substitute in vim

Tags: regex, vim, regex-group, string-substitution

Given string:

```
 some_function(inputId = "select_something"),
 (...)
 some_other_function(inputId = "some_other_label")
```

I would like to arrive at:

```
 some_function(inputId = ns("select_something")),
 (...)
 some_other_function(inputId = ns("some_other_label"))
```

The key change here is the element **`ns( ... )`** that surrounds the string available in the `""` after the `inputId`

## Regex

So far, I have came up with this regex:

```
:%substitute/\(inputId\s=\s\)\(\"[a-zA-Z]"\)/\1ns(/2/cgI
```

However, when deployed, it produces an error:

> E488: Trailing characters

A simpler version of that regex works, the syntax:

```
:%substitute/\(inputId\s=\s\)/\1ns(/cgI
```

would correctly inser **`ns(`** after finding `inputId =` and create string

```
some_other_function(inputId = ns("some_other_label")
```

### Challenge

I'm struggling to match the remaining part of the string, ex. `"select_something")` and return it as:

```
"select_something"))
```

.

Comment: The `E488: Trailing characters` is because you have a `/2` in the replace part that should be `\2`.

Comment: This works on your examples but no doubt it will get more trickier than that once you have escaped double quotes.`%s/\v\(inputid \= \zs(".{-}")\ze\)/ns(&)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems with your regex.

1. `[a-zA-Z]` will only match one letter. Presumably you want to match everything up to the next `"`, so you'll need a `\+` and you'll also need to match underscores too. I would recommend `\w\+`. Unless more than `[a-zA-Z_]` might be in the string, in which case I would do `.\{-}`.
2. You have a `/2` instead of `\2`. This is why you're getting **E488**.

I would do this:

```
:%s/\(inputId = \)\(".\{-}\)"/\1ns(\2)/cgI
```

Or use the *start match* atom: (that is, `\zs`)

```
:%s/inputId = \zs\".\{-}"/ns(&)/cgI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated character class `"[^"]*"` to match a quoted string:

```
%s/\(inputId\s*=\s*\)\("[^"]*"\)/\1ns(\2)/g
```